# Boolean comparison of dereferenced int* and int failing in C

Tags: c, pointers, int, dereference

I'm writing a program in C on Debian Linux x64. In part of the code, I have the following if statement:

```
if (*all_drops >= (npes * 128)) {
            break;
}
```

`all_drops` is an `int*` which has been assigned an `int`'s worth of memory, while `npes` is an `int` with the value 2. Therefore, the if statement should be true when the value in `all_drops` is at least 256. However, I've had the variable get above 1000 without the if statement evaluating true.

I'm not sure if there's some nuance in comparing dereferenced pointers to other numbers, but I've searched Google and haven't been able to find any similar issues (which leads me to believe I am missing something). Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: no way! can you show us the entire loop?

Comment: The issue is definitely not in the comparison, which does what you seem to think it does. How do you assign addresses to `all_drops`?

Comment: It should work, probably the problem is elsewhere; can you isolate a minimum compilable code snippet that exhibits the problem?

Comment: How are you assigning all_drops?

Comment: I'm working on getting a code snippet that fails reliably. @Magnus Hoff and @Matteo Italia are correct, the comparison works fine, the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as intented:
http://ideone.com/DjHGI

I guess the problem can be in the way you're initializing `*all_drops`